# How can we fill in some missing details in this proof?

Tags: proof-verification, metric-spaces, proof-writing, uniform-convergence, alternative-proof

Let $(X,d)$ and $(Y,\rho)$ be metric spaces and $X$ is compact. Suppose $f:X\to Y$ and $f_n:X\to Y$ are continuous functions such that for every $x\in X$,  $\rho(f_n(x),f(x))$ decreases to $0$ as $n\to\infty$. Show that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$.

My working:

We can apply the Dini's Theorem as follows:

WLOG let $(f_n)$ be monotonically increasing sequence of continuous functions. Since for every $x\in X$, $\rho(f_n(x),f(x))$ decreases to $0$ as $n\to\infty$, then $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ for every $x\in X$ and hence $f_n\to f$ pointwise. Since $f$ is continuous. Then by Dini's Theorem $f_n\to f$ uniformly.

But I have some doubts in my proof:

1. What if $(f_n)$ is neither monotonically increasing nor decreasing, is it possible if $f_n$ is alternating but $\rho(f_n(x),f(x))$ still decreases to $0$?
2. I am not sure how can $\rho(f_n(x),f(x))$ decreases to $0$ implies $f_n\to f$ pointwise. I did not write the details in my proof because I am not sure whether or not $\rho(f_n(x),f(x))$ decreases to $0$ really implies $f_n\to f$ pointwise. If yes, how can we fill the details?
3. Is my overall proof correct? If not how can we fix it (by still using Dini's Theorem)?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all $x\in X$, we have $\rho(f_n(x),f(x))\geqslant \rho(f_{n+1}(x),f(x))$. It follows that $$\sup_{x\in X}\rho(f_n(x),f(x))\geqslant\sup_{x\in X} \rho(f_{n+1}(x),f(x)).$$ Since $\lim_{n\to\infty} \rho(f_n(x),f(x))=0$ for all $x\in X$ we conclude that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{x\in X} \rho(f_n(x),f(x))=0,$$ and hence $f_n$ converges uniformly.